# Destroy all issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I have a standard has_many/belongs_to relationship with movies and posters. Each movie can have many posters. I have the following in a rake command:

```
task remove_movie_posters: :environment do
   destroyed = Movie.where(fake: true).posters.where("created_at < ?", 1.minute.ago).destroy_all
   puts "Done. " + destroyed.length + " records deleted."
end
```

but I get the error: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`destroy_all` returns an integer and you cannot concatinate strings and integers like that. A simple example to show this problem is:

```
"foo" + 42 + "bar"
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
```

The solution is to use string interpolation (or the `to_s` method, but that feels ugly to me):

```
puts "Done. #{destroyed.length} records deleted."
```